# is chaining GET and POST requests bad?

Tags: python, file-upload, aiohttp

I'm trying to upload some file to my file hosting service. I'm using `aiohttp` for it.

My server is quite limited in storage and I thought of chaining GET and POST requests, so I don't have to download the file to local. I used the example given in the documentation of `aiohttp` as a starting point to test my setup. Turns out i'm seeing some upload speed difference. Chained one is having reduced speed. Now i'm curious to know whether the setup is bad.

```
resp = await session.get('http://python.org')
await session.post('http://httpbin.org/post',
                   data=resp.content)
```

This is the example given in documentation and i'm using this, but i'm uploading files of greater size (like GB's)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently wrong with calling a GET then taking data returned from that GET and using it to call a POST. This is kinda the idea behind RESTful apis.

Now calling a GET and it returns a lot of data and then to turn around and send all that data to a POST where the POST is only looking for a certain part of that data would at worst be a waste of bandwidth and resources. But nothing harmful should come from it.